# Как использовать WindowsMediaplayer в С#. Несколько звуковых потоков одновременно

Tags: c#, аудио

Как использовать несколько звуковых семплов?

Например у меня в папке Resources есть сlap.wav getQuest.wav и например clash.wav. Как их использовать в проекте одновременно!

Мне предложили использовать вот такой метод, но он не работает тишина.

```
SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();

    Dictionary<string, System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream> selector = new Dictionary<string, System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream>();

    // Вызываем один раз при старте
    private void Init()
    {
        selector.Add("colision", Properties.Resources.clap);
        selector.Add("getQuestion", Properties.Resources.getQuest);
        //...
    }

    private void playSound(string wth2play = "")
    {
        soundEnabled = true;


        if (soundEnabled)
        {
            if (selector.ContainsKey(wth2play))
            {
                soundPlayer.Stream = selector[wth2play];
                soundPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

мне предложили еще такой метод тоже неработает. (не понимаю как выташить из ресурсов файлы)

```
        var player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Open(Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("mySound"));
        player.Play();
```

Comment: Если вы хотите задать вопрос про загрузку ресурсов, то так и сформулируйте, очень желательно с примером, в котором воспроизводится проблема. А пока это дубликат предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: к примеру второй вариант как мне достать из ресурсов файл и проиграить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эх, я поторопился с рекомендацией пользоваться ресурсами WPF: конкретно `MediaPlayer` их не поддерживает, потому что реализован через собственно виндовый Media Player, который не умеет доставать данные из ресурсов. Сравнение возможностей `SoundPlayer` и `MediaPlayer` можно найти в статье [WPF Audio Player](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235083/WPF-Audio-Player) (раздел "Comparison of SoundPlayer and MediaPlayer").

Вам придётся добавлять файлы WAV как Build Action = Content, Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer. Тогда загрузка будет выглядеть так:

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(new Uri("Resources/Sound.wav", UriKind.Relative));
player.Play();
```

Вы можете положить звуки в ресурсы, но извлекать их в файлы всё равно придётся, причём вручную и надо будет беспокоиться об удалении временных файлов, в общем, овчинка не стоит выделки.

Answer (score 3):

Вам звуковые файлы лучше положить в отдельную папочку, как посоветовал товарищ Discord и, мой совет, воспользоваться классом `Audio` из пространства имён `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback`.

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;

...

//в каком-нибудь методе
Audio audio = new Audio("Sound1.wav");
audio.Play();   //не уверен, обязательно ли вызывать Play, но думаю, что да
audio = new Audio("Sound2.wav");
audio.Play();   //обе дорожки будут воспроизводиться одновременно.
```

Comment: кричит, что такого имени нету DirectX, мне нужно скачать DirectX SDK?

Comment: @jcmax, правой кнопкой по проекту -> `Добавить ссылку`, нажать кнопку `Обзор`, перейти в папку `C:\windows\assembly\ GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback`. Нужная DLL должна быть в этой папке. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015252/4278250

Comment: Managed DirectX давно объявлен устаревшим, поэтому я бы не рекомендовал его использовать. Указанной библиотеки может и не быть в GAC'е. Придётся скачивать SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Достать файл из ресурсов можно так:

```
    Stream My_Stream = Properties.Resources.сlap;
    SoundPlayer MySPlayer = new SoundPlayer(My_Stream);
    MySPlayer.Play();
```

Чтобы запустить одновременно два файла, попробуйте этот код:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
    Stream My_Stream1 = Properties.Resources.сlap;
    SoundPlayer MySPlayer1 = new SoundPlayer(My_Stream1);
    MySPlayer1.Play();
}).Start();

new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
    Stream My_Stream2 = Properties.Resources.clash;
    SoundPlayer MySPlayer2 = new SoundPlayer(My_Stream2);
    MySPlayer2.Play();
}).Start();
```

Comment: Ругается на потоки !

Comment: Что пишет? Потому что у этот код работает.